# index in a loop by using ..<

Tags: swift

I didn't understood the concept of the For-In loop in swift 3 , can anyone explain to us it m thanks in advance

```
var total = 0
for i in 0..<4 {
total += i
}
print(total)
```

The result of total is 6 , Why ?

Comment: 1+2+3 = 6 ? You loop from 0 to smaller than 4, mean 0 -> 3

Comment: Try putting a `print` statement in the loop and log the values of `total` and `i` at each iteration – that will show you what's happening.

Comment: what if it is 0..<5

Comment: @MalikTürk, then it would be `0+1+2+3+4 = 10`

Comment: and just to be clear - if you have for i in 0...4, the value of i will be 0, 1, 2, 3, 4

Comment: @user28434 but when i run it , it give 11

Comment: I would also recommend having a read of the [range operator section of the language guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH6-ID73).

Comment: @MalikTürk [No it doesn't](http://swift.sandbox.bluemix.net/#/repl/591d6bd0a1cd601a30972e38)

Comment: @user28434 i assumed the value of total as 1 then all values are executed as total +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i=0 =>
total = 0+0 =0

i=1 =>
total = 0+1 = 1

i=2 =>
total = 1+2 = 3

i=3 =>
total = 3+3 =6

it's simply alogrithm ;-)

i never reach 4 because you said it STRICTLY inferior to 4 =)

(Do I answer your question?)

Comment: Thank you , but when i change it to 0..<5  it give 11 rather than 10 :/

Comment: You need to change 0...4 if you want to execute fro 0 to 4

Comment: @Tristan I made a mistake , i assumed the value of total as 1 , then all values are executed total +1

Answer (score 0):

Your loop will be vary from 0 to 3 i.e. 0,1,2,3 but if you want it will vary from 0 to 4 then try this -

```
var total = 0
for i in 0...4 {
total += i
}
print(total)
```